# Leaving out parts of legend based on a certain value ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have line graph with many groups, most of them are grey but the top `n` is colored. There are too many groups to leave a legend for, since it overwhelms the graph. I want the legend to reflect only the top `n` groups.

This is some example data that I created to simulate the problem:

```
require(tidyverse)

test_data <- tribble(
~year, ~number, ~group,
1, 10, 1,
1, 7, 2,
1, 5, 3,
1, 2, 4,
1, 1, 5,
1, .5, 6,
2, 10, 1,
2, 7, 2,
2, 5, 3,
2, 2.5, 4,
2, 2, 5,
2, 3, 6,
)


scheme <- tribble(
 ~group, ~color,
  1, 'red',
  2, 'blue',
  3, 'green',
  4, 'grey',
  5, 'grey',
  6, 'grey'
)

test_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, number, color = factor(group))) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(labels = scheme$group,
                 values = scheme$color)
```

This creates a plot:
[image]

With all 6 groups in the legend. Is it possible to make the legend only reflect the ones that are not grey? (i.e., subset the legend by some rule?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `NA` for every group you want to hide in the `breaks` argument of the `scale_color_manual`.

```
test_data %>%
    ggplot(aes(year, number, color = factor(group))) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_color_manual(labels = scheme$group,
                       values = scheme$color,
                       breaks = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA))
```

[image]